# Trying to delete all non numeric columns from a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to delete all non numeric columns from a dataframe in RStudio

Using line:

```
colnames(train)= mutate_if(as.numeric(as.character(colnames(train))))
```

Error:

> no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using select from `dplyr`. First create a data frame (replace df with your dataframe)

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,3,2,5),Char=c(1,2,"six",7))

  ID Char
1  1    1
2  3    2
3  2  six
4  5    7
```

deleting all non numeric columns by selecting columns which only contain numerics

```
newdf <- df %>% select(where(is.numeric))
```

Output

```
   ID
1  1
2  3
3  2
4  5
```